# Umbraco Contour Workflow return to form?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

I would need to do some advanced validation on a form I am building with Contour, this validation includes a couple of fields, external webservice and such things.

My idea was to define a new workflow, create it and set it up...the idea would be if it fails that it returns the user to the form...however I cannot find a way to return the user to the form through workflow.

I've tried RecordService methods (GoToPage, PreviousPage, NextPage...), I've tried returning Cancelled or Failed status from the workflow...but nothing seems to work, I always get redirected to the Thank You page.

Can anyone help me? How can I do this?

Comment: This may be best asked in the Our.Umbraco.com forums: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour

Comment: @BeaverProj - it was posted there http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/20348-Contour-Workflow-return-to-form - with no response.  Feels like a Contour bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the Contour Dev Docs: http://umbraco.com/pro-downloads/contour//ContourDeveloperDocs.pdf there is a ValidateSettings() method mentioned on page 9.

Also, this blog post seemed useful: http://farmcode.org/post/2010/03/26/Regionalizing-validation-messages-and-regex-in-Umbraco-Contour.aspx

I admit I haven't actually done what you're trying to do yet.  Although I have added my own custom workflow, it didn't require any validation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Tim Geyssens (Contour creator), you cannot stop a form submission via workflow.

See link for alternatives.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/37425-Go-back-to-form-when-workflow-fails